# localhost:8080/ works well but localhost:8080/phpmyadmin won't open

Tags: php, mysql, apache, web-services, phpmyadmin

I am working on Windows10 and trying to access phpmyadmin from localhost.
I am using xampp.
I created a index.php in htdocs/webservice.
The port number for apache is 8080 and mysql is 3306.

http://localhost:8080/webservice/ works fine.
but http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin doesn't.

I've tried the other stackoverflow suggestions but I can't seem to find the problem..

Below is my log

```
Version: '10.1.8-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
2016-06-06 00:54:49 2b08 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2016-06-06  0:54:49 11016 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-06-06  0:54:49 11016 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-06-06  0:54:49 11016 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2016-06-06  0:54:49 11016 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-06-06  0:54:49 11016 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2016-06-06  0:54:49 11016 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-06-06  0:54:49 11016 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2016-06-06  0:54:49 11016 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-06-06  0:54:49 11016 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-06-06  0:54:49 11016 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1835037 and 1835037 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 1835738 in the ib_logfiles!
2016-06-06  0:54:49 11016 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2016-06-06  0:54:49 11016 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2016-06-06  0:54:49 11016 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2016-06-06  0:54:49 11016 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2016-06-06  0:54:49 11016 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2016-06-06  0:54:49 11016 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-06-06  0:54:49 11016 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2016-06-06  0:54:49 11016 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.26-74.0 started; log sequence number 1835738
2016-06-06  0:54:49 11528 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2016-06-06  0:54:49 11016 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2016-06-06  0:54:49 11016 [Note] Recovering after a crash using tc.log
2016-06-06  0:54:49 11016 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
2016-06-06  0:54:49 11016 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
2016-06-06  0:54:49 11016 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2016-06-06  0:54:49 11016 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2016-06-06  0:54:49 11016 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.8-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
2016-06-06 00:56:20 3bc8 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2016-06-06  0:56:20 15304 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-06-06  0:56:20 15304 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-06-06  0:56:20 15304 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2016-06-06  0:56:20 15304 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-06-06  0:56:20 15304 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2016-06-06  0:56:20 15304 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-06-06  0:56:20 15304 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2016-06-06  0:56:20 15304 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-06-06  0:56:20 15304 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-06-06  0:56:20 15304 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1835037 and 1835037 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 1835748 in the ib_logfiles!
2016-06-06  0:56:20 15304 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2016-06-06  0:56:20 15304 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2016-06-06  0:56:21 15304 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2016-06-06  0:56:21 15304 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2016-06-06  0:56:21 15304 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2016-06-06  0:56:21 15304 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-06-06  0:56:21 15304 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2016-06-06  0:56:21 15304 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.26-74.0 started; log sequence number 1835748
2016-06-06  0:56:21 5536 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2016-06-06  0:56:21 15304 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2016-06-06  0:56:21 15304 [Note] Recovering after a crash using tc.log
2016-06-06  0:56:21 15304 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
2016-06-06  0:56:21 15304 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
2016-06-06  0:56:21 15304 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2016-06-06  0:56:21 15304 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2016-06-06  0:56:21 15304 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.8-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 8080  mariadb.org binary distribution
2016-06-06 00:58:51 211c InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2016-06-06  0:58:51 8476 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-06-06  0:58:51 8476 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-06-06  0:58:51 8476 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2016-06-06  0:58:51 8476 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-06-06  0:58:51 8476 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2016-06-06  0:58:51 8476 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-06-06  0:58:51 8476 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2016-06-06  0:58:51 8476 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-06-06  0:58:51 8476 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-06-06  0:58:51 8476 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1835037 and 1835037 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 1835758 in the ib_logfiles!
2016-06-06  0:58:51 8476 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2016-06-06  0:58:51 8476 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2016-06-06  0:58:51 8476 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2016-06-06  0:58:51 8476 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2016-06-06  0:58:51 8476 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2016-06-06  0:58:51 8476 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-06-06  0:58:51 8476 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2016-06-06  0:58:51 8476 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.26-74.0 started; log sequence number 1835758
2016-06-06  0:58:51 3104 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2016-06-06  0:58:51 8476 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2016-06-06  0:58:51 8476 [Note] Recovering after a crash using tc.log
2016-06-06  0:58:51 8476 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
2016-06-06  0:58:51 8476 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
2016-06-06  0:58:51 8476 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2016-06-06  0:58:51 8476 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2016-06-06  0:58:51 8476 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.8-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 8080  mariadb.org binary distribution
```

Comment: Check your webserver error log for hints (this is your MySQL log). Also take a look at your Apache configuration file. XAMPP does some non-standard things with configuration, but I thought the default was to listen on port 80 (so http://localhost/phpmyadmin instead of what you're trying). Also, isn't there a link on the admin/start page to directly launch phpMyAdmin? Does that work or give you an error page?

Answer (score -1):

Goto phpMyAdmin Directory inside xampp. You will find config.inc.php file. Now change this line:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

To

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1:8080';
```

Next you have to restart your server.

Comment: 'host' is the configuration directive for the MySQL host, not the listening HTTP connection and to change MySQL port there's a `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']` directive, so this doesn't seem right.